# Write console output of numbers to text file

Tags: java, arrays, fileoutputstream, printstream

quick question, I don't know what I'm missing here. If I have a console output of 9 numbers in a row, and 9 total rows, how would I go about writing that exact output to an external text file, so it looks the same way in the text file.

Assuming the console looks like this:

```
2 4 5 1 9 3 6 8 7 
9 7 6 2 5 8 4 1 3 
1 8 3 7 4 6 9 2 5 
8 5 2 3 1 9 7 4 6 
3 1 9 4 6 7 8 5 2 
7 6 4 5 8 2 3 9 1 
4 3 8 6 2 5 1 7 9 
5 9 7 8 3 1 2 6 4 
6 2 1 9 7 4 5 3 8
```

And that console output is stored in an array variable named "myArray" How would I write it to a text file so it looks just like that (or separated by commas)

So far I have this:

```
File solutionFile = new File("output.txt");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(solutionFile);
PrintStream writeOut = new PrintStream(stream);
System.setOut(writeOut);

for (int rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++) {
  for (int columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
    System.out.println(myArray[rows][columns] + " ");
  }
}
```

When it writes to the file, each number is placed on its own line. Any assistance possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the print statement a `println`, just a `print`.

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++) {
  for (int columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
    System.out.print(myArray[rows][columns] + " ");    //keep printing on the same line
  }
  System.out.println();    //go to the next line
}
```

Another thing you could do is I/O redirection. If you run the program via terminal or command prompt, you can type `java MyProgram > outputFile.txt`. The `>` redirects the console output to go to `outputFile.txt` instead of where it normally goes.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid as hell! Thanks so much!! When it lets me accept an answer in 10 minutes, I will accept this as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use following code (instead of println use just pring and call println() after second for)

```
File solutionFile = new File("output.txt");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(solutionFile);
PrintStream writeOut = new PrintStream(stream);
System.setOut(writeOut);

for (int rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++) {
  for (int columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
    System.out.print(myArray[rows][columns] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not something you need, but just to give you an idea about the other ways to do it, I put it here. The other answer is pretty much what you need.

If you are using command line to execute your java code, you can redirect STDOUT to a file by running your code like this:
`java Main > output.txt`

You can also redirect STDIN: `java Main < input.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: Yea I know about that, but I'm looking for something different. Thank you tho!